# ¿como sería la forma correcta de hacer que se descargues los pdf con bubles anidados en python haciendo webScraping?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scrapping, os

Estoy intentando hacer web Scraping de los resultados electorales de mi país, y necesito descargar unos pdf donde están los resultados por mesas, pero antes necesito recorer los puestos, zonas municipios etc. para esto hice un código con Selenium que recorre bucles anidados que pre establece una ruta y se debe actualizar en cada iteración dependiendo del puesto de votación, el código tiene como estructura general la siguiente:

```
def create_download_directory(departamento, municipio, zona, puesto):
    download_directory = os.path.abspath(f"Datos/pdf/Departamentos/{departamento}/municipios/{municipio}/Zonas/{zona}/puestos/{puesto}")
    os.makedirs(download_directory, exist_ok=True)  # Crea el directorio si no existe
    return download_directory
    
# Establecer el directorio de descargas en el directorio de trabajo actual
download_directory = create_download_directory("dummy_departamento", "dummy_municipio", "dummy_zona", "dummy_puesto")

os.makedirs(download_directory, exist_ok=True) # Crea el directorio si no existe
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "download.default_directory": download_directory,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", chrome_prefs)

# Otros ajustes

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# Definir variables fuera del bucle
departamento = "dummy_departamento"
municipio = "dummy_municipio"
zona_electoral = "dummy_zona"
puesto_votacion = "dummy_puesto"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = 'https:'
browser.get(url)

# Itera sobre las opciones de departamentos
for option_dpt in [options_dpt[4]]:
    departamento = option_dpt.text.strip()
    # Imprime el departamento actual
    print("Departamento:", option_dpt.text)
    
    
    # Itera sobre las opciones de municipios e imprime el texto
    for muni in [options_muni[8]]:
        municipio = muni.text.strip()
        print("  Municipio:", muni.text)
        
                
        # Iteramos sobre las opciones de zonas electorales e imprimimos en texto
        for zona in [option_zon[0]]:
            zona_electoral = zona.text.strip()
            print("     Zona electoral:", zona.text)
            
            
            
            # Iteramos los puestos de votacion
            for puesto in option_pues:
                puesto_votacion = puesto.text.strip()
                print("         Puesto de votacion:", puesto.text)
                
                
                
                # Configurar la opción de descarga directamente en las preferencias de ChromeOptions
                
                chrome_prefs["download.default_directory"] = download_directory
                chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", chrome_prefs)
                                              
                                                               
            # Imprimir el directorio de descarga al final de cada iteración
                print(f"Directorio de descarga al final de la iteración: {download_directory}")
                
                # Iterar sobre las mesas
                for _ in mesas_elements:
                    try:
                        # Esperar a que aparezcan los elementos de mesas
                        WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
                            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/'))
                        )
```

El problema es que luego de la primera iteración, a pesar de crear correctamente el directorio del segundo puesto de votación, guarda las descargas en directorio de la primera iteración. ¿que debería cambiar?